# Slow winforms application : should I use a local dataset?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have a c# winform application that accesses data from a database (SQL Server CE), manipulates data and stores it back. I have been something rather "noobish", as in my program retrieves data from the .sdf file every time I need the data. Instead, I think it would be better to create a dataset which is populated from thae database when the application is launched. The changes can be made to the dataset, and then the dataset data can be stored back into the database when the application closes.

I want to know if this is the right way to go, or am I missing something. Note that the dataset exists only as long as the application is running.

Comment: use SQLADapter with Dataset, waht ever the Updation on Dataset, it reflects in DAtaBase

Comment: How many users will be accessing the database? will it be only one windows app connected to the db or multiple apps?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [SqlCeResultSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceresultset%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) . It is suitable for displaying as well as updating data.